# Nontemporal writes in MSVC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, x86, memcpy

I am using MSVC (VS2013) for my application and basically calculating and writing out a large amount of data, and the bandwidth is one of my bottlenecks. Is there anyway to perform non-temporal writes on MSVC? I know intel compiler has that option, but not sure what the MSVC equivalent is. I know there is _mm_stream_ps, but my data is not in xmm/ymm registers, so I don't want to incur cost of transferring them to another register set as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about [asynchronous IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.110).aspx)? If not then what are you asking about?

Comment: not asynchronous I/O. Non-temporal writes is a way to write to memory without touching cache, ideally used in cases of streaming data to memory since cache is wasted then. https://blogs.fau.de/hager/archives/2103 explains what it is somewhat.

Comment: MSVC and all other major compilers (like gcc and clang) support Intel's intrinsics for x86 targets.  re: part2: look up the intrinsic for the MOVNTI instruction; it takes an integer register as the source.  However, if you're bottlenecked on memory bandwidth and not ALU throughput, then it might be worth combining your data into 128b vectors for use with MOVNTPS.